Indesign, table: How to horizontally align text and object in table cell
I want to have a cell where I have text flush left, then a graphic slightly taller than the text object flush right.
How do I horizontally align them? W/out the objects the text easily center-aligns, but with the graphic objects the text bottom-aligns with the graphic object.
I want to avoid taking the graphic out of the table and just place it ontop in the hierarchy as this document will be slightly adjusted for different versions and would have to be manually adjusted every time.

Select the graphic using the Selection Tool and choose  Object > Anchored Object > Options... and adjust the Y offset... or... Select the object as text using the Type Tool, and adjust the Baseline Shift on the Character panel.

Both works, 2nd was easier to work with when there are 3 cells with the same style and the objects are not the same height. (At least in this instance)

I have had this issue and yes, Scott's second solution is the quicker & cleaner one. You can also insert a right indent tab in between the left side (text) and the right side (graphic), to stick these to the left and right edges of the cell, without having to control the size of the gap between them.

If you only have a few objects, the easiest thing is probably just to do as Scott’s answer describes.
If your table starts growing and you have more cells, it makes more sense to let your Anchored Object Options do all the work for you and save them in an object style that you can easily apply with a single click.
For example, in the screenshot below, I’ve created a simple table with three rows (vertically centred), written a few words in each cell and pasted in three frames of different heights and colours to illustrate. All three boxes have the object style Vertically centred applied, and this style only defines one thing: options for positioning the object if it’s anchored inside another frame:

The anchored object options are what InDesign uses to determine a specific point on the page’s X/Y axis where the anchored object is placed, the placement point.
At the top, the Position option can either be Inline (the object is treated as just another character, taking up space and flowing like regular text inside the line; the placement point is then just the insertion point where the object is anchored) or Custom (the object is removed from the text flow, and the placement point is calculated based exclusively on the following options – akin to absolute positioning in CSS). Here, Custom is chosen.
The settings in the Anchored Object section define what particular point on the anchored object should be positioned on the placement point, the anchor point. Here, the reference point is set to the centre right point, so when the placement point is determined, the anchored object will be placed with its centre point on the right side on the placement point.
The settings in the Anchored Position section are where you define where the placement point itself should be. Here again, the reference point is set to the centre right point. Unlike the anchor point (which is always based on the geometry of the anchored object), the placement point is defined based on the geometry of a container, and you can choose which container to use for both the X and Y axes.
In this case, since a table cell is a type of column, I’ve chosen to set both the vertical and horizontal base to Column Edge, meaning that the position point will be vertically centred on the rightmost edge of the containing column (= table cell).
In other words, the settings shown tells InDesign to place the anchored object so that the centre right point of the anchored object is positioned on the centre right point of the table cell it’s in.
